# Laravel FacebookProvider Error. Undefined variable: access_token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I have strange problem with facebook provider in my project (Laravel 5.2);

```
Undefined variable: access_token vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php 80
```

It's strange because it worked long time and now i have error.
Nothing was changed in my code.

Answer (score 8):

I make a patch and it works for me. In  **vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php** Replace

```
parse_str($body, $data);
return $access_token;
```

With

```
parse_str($body, $data);
$json = json_decode(key($data));
return $json->access_token;
```

Comment: It's working now :)

Comment: It says, undefined index access_token ....

Comment: @WaqasAliKhanPuar what's your version of Manager? If you have v3, then use different code...https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Manager/issues/86

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the depreciation of v2.2 Graph API.

Checkout the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) at facebook.

In v2.3 Graph API, Oauth Access Token calls now return a valid JSON message insted of an encoded URL.

The new format of this response is {"access_token": {TOKEN}, "token_type":{TYPE}, "expires_in":{TIME}}.

Comment: I'm curious if this is not a facebook issue. Stackoveflow also having problem with Facebook login. After Facbook log in 
**Facebook Data Query Failed**

Comment: Same problem on "fakturowania.pl".

Comment: Have the same with Laravel